# Non-EQ relation error Cassandra - how fix primary key?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-cli

I created a one table **posts**. When I make request SELECT:

```
return $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM "posts" WHERE "id" IN(:id) LIMIT '.$this->limit_per_page, ['id' => $id]);
```

I get error:

> PRIMARY KEY column "id" cannot be restricted (preceding column
>   "post_at" is either not restricted or by a non-EQ relation)

My table dump is:

```
CREATE TABLE posts (
  id       uuid,
  post_at  timestamp,
  user_id  bigint,
  name     text,
  category set<text>,
  link     varchar,
  image    set<varchar>,
  video    set<varchar>,
  content  map<text, text>,
  private  boolean,
  PRIMARY KEY (user_id,post_at,id)
  )
  WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (post_at DESC);
```

I read some article about PRIMARY AND CLUSTER KEYS, and understood, when there are some primary keys - I need use operator **=** with **IN**. In my case, i can not use a one PRIMARY KEY. What you advise me to change in table structure, that error will disappear?

Comment: just try interchanging user_id and id in primary key, Also to use = operator add a column which has value you know eg clom1 with value 1

Comment: There is not clom1 such as i know value, all content are different, i can create additional clom1 and add there is always value 1 for each row?

Comment: yes you will have to create a column which has fixed value which you can use

Comment: I change that you advised: Have a query now: `return $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM "posts" WHERE "index_field" = :index AND "id" IN(:id) LIMIT '.$this->limit_per_page, ['id' => $id, 'index' => 1]);` `Get error: 'Syntax_error: line 1:45 no viable alternative at input 'index'`

Comment: Please, can you response me more extanded with a example? Thank you

Comment: I changed interchanged user_id and id in primary key and used query select * from posts where id in (comma separated id's)

Comment: I also changed, but does not work: `PRIMARY KEY (id, post_at, user_id)`

Comment: I need use WHERE for column **user_id** If i change - it will be wotk: `PRIMARY KEY column "user_id" cannot be restricted (preceding column "post_at" is either not restricted or by a non-EQ relation)` I propose you to write answer with a more deyails, that we understand each other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My dummy table structure

```
CREATE TABLE posts (
  id       timeuuid,
  post_at  timestamp,
  user_id  bigint,
  PRIMARY KEY (id,post_at,user_id)
  )
  WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (post_at DESC);
```

And after inserting some dummy data

I ran query `select * from posts where id in (timeuuid1,timeuuid2,timeuuid3);`

I was using cassandra 2.0 with cql 3.0

Comment: Thank you, can you check please if work LIMIT at your query? Also I use filed **user_id** for operator **WHERE**. I told this already, please, try with user_id field. Tahnk you very much.

Comment: Oh, sorry I confused myself. I will check your version now

Comment: When I use query: `SELECT * FROM "posts" WHERE "id" IN(20b40eb5-4174-4762-a7fe-1ab8299e5da3, 627a42e1-64a0-4be8-b307-a012b8a8d889); `In result query i get 0 rows, however at table **posts** there are id with same **id UUID**

Comment: if you are using cassandra cluster it might be consistency issue. Also why tablename and column name are in quotes?

Comment: Yes, thank you, you are profi. But a little question, how to compare true/false value in WHERE operator?

Comment: According to documentation boolean datatypes are used as strings